# How to write C++ ISR with MSP432 DriverLib'c C code?

Tags: c++, c, microcontroller, interrupt, msp432

I want to use `C++` as my main programming language for my microcontroller (MSP432) projects.

I wrote some simple scripts not involving *interrupt service routines* (*ISR*). They all worked fine. The code had looked like the following:

```cpp
/* MSP and DriverLib includes */
/* no <<extern "C">> needed due to the header files implement it. */
#include <ti/devices/msp432p4xx/driverlib/driverlib.h>

int main()
{
    /* Some C++ code here that worked fine. */
}
```

Now I wanted to upgrade my code to have simple ISR like for UART communication (serial PC interface). So I did this:

```cpp
/* MSP and DriverLib includes */
/* no <<extern "C">> needed due to the header files implement it. */
#include <ti/devices/msp432p4xx/driverlib/driverlib.h>

int main()
{
    /* Some C++ code here that worked fine. */
}

void EUSCIA0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    /* Some C++ code here that worked fine. */
}
```

The issue with this code is that the ISR is not get triggered. Instead the default ISR from the DriverLib is called. I wondered and started to try digging myself.

At some point I *accidentally* put `extern "C"` around the ISR defined in the C++ part of the source code. And it worked:

```cpp
/* MSP and DriverLib includes */
/* no <<extern "C">> needed due to the header files implement it. */
#include <ti/devices/msp432p4xx/driverlib/driverlib.h>

int main()
{
    /* Some C++ code here that worked fine. */
}

extern "C"
{

    void EUSCIA0_IRQHandler(void)
    {
        /* Only C code here works fine. */
    }

}
```

I assume since "I" (DriverLib) registered the ISR vectors and `extern` ISR signatures in the C (not the C++) part of the source code, my C++ ISR is some kind out of scope for the ISR signature..

**1) Am I right?**

But there is a catch. Since I *moved* my C++ ISR into C *context* I am not able to use C++ code e.g. classes etc. anymore within the ISR.

**2) How to keep C++ within the ISR within the C++ part of the source code without touching DriverLib's ISR initialization (e.g. `startup_msp432p401r_ccs.c`)?**

- C++ stuff is `C++03`
- C stuff is `C89`

Comment: The ISR is not finding the function because the actual function name in the object code is *different* from the one in source code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C.2B.2B Whereas with `extern "C"` the C++ name mangling is not applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the driver library is static (i.e. `.a`), you can do:

```
extern "C" void EUSCIA0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    // whatever ...
}
```

This should replace the standard function with yours [which you can check with `nm`, etc.]. And, when the driver library registers the ISR function, it should catch yours instead of its internal one

I believe you can now call `c++` code from this function.

---

If not, you may need:

```
void cplus_plus_handler(void)
{
    // whatever ...
}

extern "C" void EUSCIA0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    cplus_plus_handler();
}
```

This probably works as is. But, `cplus_plus_handler` may need to be in a separate `.cpp` file [with the C handler in a `.c`].

---

If the library is dynamic (i.e. `.so`, `.dll`), you may need to call a registration function to attach your ISR function.